# How can I create a 32-64-character top-level NEAR account without a .near suffix?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account#account-id-rules says that account IDs must be 2 to 64 characters, and currently `MIN_ALLOWED_TOP_LEVEL_ACCOUNT_LENGTH` = 32, so top-level accounts of 32 to 64 characters are available without needing to be purchased at auction.

It also says:

> Currently all `mainnet` accounts use a `near` top-level account name (ex `example.near`)

My guess is that "currently" means not just that there don't happen to be any other top-level accounts now but that there *cannot* be until a future change in NEAR protocol.

Where can I see the source code related to this statement?

And is there a public roadmap / timeline somewhere stating when (auctioned and non-auctioned) top-level accounts will become available?

Answer (score 2):

given how account and account names are implemented (an account is actually a smart contract) the use of "near" as as a root-level account is needed.
".near" is actually an account with a smart contract deployed on it:
https://explorer.near.org/accounts/near

Anything related to account id (names) can be found here:
https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/master/core/account-id/src/lib.rs